# Matrix, hermitian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ be a hermitian matrix and $A^2 = O$. Then prove that $A=O$. 
For me, this question is little bit confusing, it seem to be obvious, but no idea how to prove it.

Comment: What is $O$? The zero matrix?

Comment: Yes it is zero matrix.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is hermitian, you can diagonalize it: $A=U\Sigma U^*$. Then $A^2=U\Sigma^2U^*=O$, which gives $\Sigma^2=O$. So all eigenvalues are 0, which implies $A$ is the O matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$$(A^2)_{ii} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ik}a_{ki} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ik}a_{ik}^{*} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{ik}|^2 = 0 \implies a_{ik} = 0 \implies A = 0$$

Since $A$ is Hermitian, $a_{ki} = a_{ik}^{*}$.